# Generric search function at generic link list

Tags: c, linked-list, generic-programming

I have [generic link list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-linked-list-in-c-2/) in C that know how to push struct to list.

The problem is the I can't implement generic search in those link list:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stddef.h>

struct Node
{
 
    void  *data;
 
    struct Node *next;
};
 
 
void push(struct Node** head_ref, void *new_data, size_t data_size)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
 
    new_node->data  = malloc(data_size);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
 
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<data_size; i++)
        *(char *)(new_node->data + i) = *(char *)(new_data + i);
 
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

struct A 
{
    int a1;
    long a2;
};

struct B
{
    long b1;
    int b2;
};

void find_a1_in_a_list (int desire_a1 , struct Node *a_list)
{
    struct A *a;
    while(NULL != a_list)
    {
        a = (struct A*) a_list->data;
        if(a->a1 == desire_a1)
            printf("found!\n");
        a_list = a_list->next;
    }

}



void find_b1_in_b_list (long desire_b1 , struct Node *b_list)
{
    struct B *b;
    while(NULL != b_list)
    {
        b = (struct B*) b_list->data;
        if(b->b1 == desire_b1)
            printf("found!\n");
        b_list = b_list->next;
    }

}

void find_generic (void* desire_value,int off,struct Node *list)
{

    while(NULL != list)
    {

        void* check_value_void = list->data + off;
        int check_value_cast = *(int *) check_value_void; //How to know if cast to int or long ?????
        if(check_value_cast == *(int *)desire_value) //How to know if cast to int or long ?????
            printf("found generic!\n");
        list = list->next;
    }
}
void main()
{
    struct Node *a_list = NULL; 
    struct A  a;
    a.a1=1;
    a.a2=2;
    push(&a_list, &a, sizeof(struct A)); 
    find_a1_in_a_list(1,a_list);

    struct Node *b_list = NULL; 
    struct B  b;
    b.b1=1;
    b.b2=2;
    push(&b_list, &b, sizeof(struct B));  
    find_b1_in_b_list(1,b_list);


    //tried to make it generic
    int search = 3;
    find_generic(&search,offsetof(struct A, a2),a_list);


}
```

As you can I tried to makes generic search in function `find_generic` by passing the offset to the value in struct, that code works but only for `int`

but how can I pass to this generic function if I want to search int or long ,so I will know how to makes cast ?

Is there any way to cast void * by size so I can pass `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(long)` and makes the casting by this value? or maybe another way?

Comment: You should check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-linked-list-in-c-2/

Comment: @MartinVéronneau what do you mean? this list was taken from their site , but I ask about add some option to this code accroding to my test

Comment: You didn't ask for a search function before your edits ; you just asked for a generic link list that supported any types of data.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the compare function directly instead of playing with `offsetof`/`sizeof` will be more flexible:

```
struct Node *find_generic (struct Node *list,
                           int (*fn_cmp)(void const *a, void const *b),
                           void const *data)
{
    while (list) {
        if (fn_cmp(list->data, data) == 0)
            break;
        list = list->next;
    }
    return list;
}
```

and then create custom compare functions

```
static int cmp_A(void const *a_, void const *b_)
{
    struct A const *a = a_;
    struct A const *b = b_;

    if (a->a1 == b->a1 && a->a2 == b->a2)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

and call it like

```
struct A key = {
  .a1 = 23,
  .a2 = 42,
};

find_generic(a_list, cmp_A, &key);
```

Comment: no; I mean the function argument.  I made it more clear and added an example how to use it...

Comment: thank  1) I can't use this syntax `.a1 = 23,` that c not cpp 2) I can't Passing the compare function directly , because it a list , so I need to add the offset each time

Comment: 1) you asked about c, not c++, 2) I do not understand this requirement...